# Removing any script action from text

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a script that will detect and remove any potentially malicious script inserted by the user while posting something.

That was the easy part. The **harder** part is stopping all sneaky users by making sure all variations are detected. A simple regex can detect

```
<script>something</script>
```

but will fail on

```
<script>something</ script>
```

So I tried writing the rules as flexible as I could, considering regex isn't my strong suit.

There are 3 rules:

- Remove script tags.
- Disable attributes like "onclick".
- Remove prefix 'javascript:' from links.

Here:

```
content.replace(/<[\s]*script[^>]*>[\w|\t|\r\|\W]*?<[\/\s]*script[^>]*>/gi, "");
content.replace(/<*\s(on[A-Za-z]*[\s]*=)/gi, " ignoreme=");
content.replace(/<*[\s]*(href)*(javascript:)/gi, "");
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/45tgzmcy/).

I could really use an expert advise in making this code more efficient or to point out any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your regex

```
/<[\s]*script[^>]*>[\w|\t|\r\|\W]*?<[\/\s]*script[^>]*>/gi
```

with

```
/<\s*script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<[\/\s]*script[^>]*>/gi
```

- removed unnecesary `[]`
- replaced `[\w|\t|\r\|\W]` with `[\s\S]` (both are equivalent)

You can also replace

```
/<*\s(on[A-Za-z]*[\s]*=)/gi
```

with

```
/<*\s(on[A-Za-z]*\s*=)/gi
```

and the following

```
/<*[\s]*(href)*(javascript:)/gi
```

with

```
/<*\s*(href)*(javascript:)/gi
```